# Accessing Angular Object From app.js in my HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular and am struggling with something that's probably pretty easy.

Throughout my HTML I am able to access values of an object like this `{{settings.color}}`

However, when trying to use similar methods in my JavaScript, such as `var color = {{settings.color}}` or `var color = $scope.settings.color` the variables end up being undefined.

In my app.js I have an object set up as like this.

```
$scope.products = {

      'newObj': {
          name: 'New Object',
          settings: {
              color : "red ",
              height : 2
              }
       }
 }
```

In my index.html I'd like to be able to access this object.

Just a bit confused on a quick project I was starting with to get into learning Angular.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the $scope.settings with an empty object, before assigning the value to the color,

```
$scope.settings ={};
```

**EDIT:**

With the new update , you can access it as `<h1>{{products.newObj.settings.color}}</h1>`

**DEMO**

```js
var mid = angular.module('mid', [])
mid.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope){ 
     $scope.products = {
      'newObj': {
          name: 'New Object',
          settings: {
              color : "red ",
              height : 2
              }
       }
 }
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mid">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js">   </script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
 <h1>{{products.newObj.settings.color}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```